# Need better proof: $\mid \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\mid \le \sqrt{\mid a - b \mid} $ , if $a \ge 0 \thinspace and \thinspace b\ge0$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove the inequality: $\mid \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\mid \le \sqrt{\mid a - b \mid}  $ , if $a \ge 0 \thinspace and \thinspace b\ge0$.

This is a homework and I have solved it with 2 method:

1st method: Prove with the graphic of 2 squres overlap, whose ares are a and b;

2nd method: Separate $a \ge 0 , b \ge 0$ into 5 conditions below and prove $\mid \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\mid \le \sqrt{\mid a - b \mid}  \thinspace $ holds for each condition. Druing the proof, I used triangle inequality and average inequality.
$ (1)\thinspace\thinspace a=0 ,b=0 \thinspace\thinspace(2)\thinspace \thinspace a=0 ,b>0 \thinspace\thinspace(3)\thinspace \thinspace a>0, b=0 \thinspace\thinspace(4)\thinspace \thinspace a>0 ,b>0 ,a\neq b \thinspace\thinspace(5)\thinspace \thinspace a>0, b>0 , a=b \thinspace \thinspace$

I think my solution is neither simple nor efficient.

Can you give me a better proof ?
Think you！

Comment: More solutions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2394527/42969

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$|\sqrt a-\sqrt b|=\frac{|a-b|}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}=\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{|a-b|}}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}}\sqrt{|a-b|}\tag 1$$

$$|a-b|\leq a+b\leq a+b+2\sqrt{a}{\sqrt b}=(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)^2\tag 2$$

The first inequality in $(2)$ is due to triangular inequality.

From $(2)$, it follows that$\sqrt {|a-b|}\leq \sqrt a+\sqrt b$.

So the blue colored part in $(1)$ is $\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Square both hands to get $$a + b - 2\sqrt{ab} \leq |a - b|.$$
If $a \geq b$, then the right hand side becomes $a - b$, and hence the inequality can be rewritten as $$(a + b) - (a - b) \leq 2\sqrt{ab}.$$
This can be simplified to $$2b \leq 2\sqrt{ab},$$
which should be obviously true due to our assumption that $a \geq b$.

The case where $a < b$ can be solved similarly.

Answer (score 1):

I usually think of this as a consequence of the concavity of the square root by writing it as
$$
\sqrt a -\sqrt b \leq \sqrt{a-b} - \sqrt 0
$$
when $a\geq b$. Indeed, the derivative of a concave function $u$ is decreasing and so
$$
\int_b^{b+(a-b)} u' \leq \int_0^{a-b} u'
$$
This is easy to see on a drawing: "jumping of a size $a-b$ makes a bigger effect close to $0$".

---

Notice also the advantage that this work for any concave function, so for example $x^\theta$ with $\theta \in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

We take $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$.

Then $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$
are well-defined.

We wish to prove:
$$
| \sqrt{a}- \sqrt{b} | \leq \sqrt{ | a - b |} \tag{1}
$$

Clearly, proving (1) is equivalent to proving the following:

$$
| \sqrt{a}- \sqrt{b} |^2 \leq [\sqrt{ | a - b |}]^2
$$
or
$$
| \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} |^2 \leq | a - b | 
$$
or
$$
a + b - 2 \sqrt{a b} \leq | a - b | \tag{2}
$$

We have two cases to consider:

Case 1: When $a \geq b$

In this case, $| a - b | = a - b$.

Then (2) can be simplified as
$$
a + b - 2 \sqrt{a b} \leq a - b
$$
or
$$
2 b \leq 2 \sqrt{a b}
$$
or
$$
b \leq \sqrt{a b} \tag{3}
$$

Since by assumption in Case 1, $a \geq b$, it is immediate that
$$
\sqrt{a b} \geq \sqrt{b \times b} = \sqrt{b^2} = b.
$$

Thus, we have established that (3) is true.

Case 2: When $a < b$.

In this case, $| a - b | = b - a$.

Then (2) can be simplified as
$$
a + b - 2 \sqrt{a b} \leq b - a
$$
or
$$
2 a \leq 2 \sqrt{a b}
$$
or
$$
a \leq \sqrt{a b} \tag{4}
$$

Since by assumption in Case 2, $b > a$, it is immediate that
$$
\sqrt{a b} > \sqrt{a \times a} = \sqrt{a^2} = a.
$$

Thus, we have established that (4) is true.

The proof is complete by combining Cases 1 and 2. $\ \ \ $ $\blacksquare$

Comment: Is that not the same proof as Vtand ?